# Creating a Button to Make Buttons

Tags: objective-c

I have a setup to create a UI Button when another button is clicked. Everything seemed straightforward at first, until I decided to create my own UI Button class. Most of it works, except for the fact that the button does not show up on the screen. I already have a few ideas on what might be causing it, but it would be helpful to have another pair of eyes look at the code.

customButton.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame   //this function was provided
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //this is stuff I wrote, that could be wrong.
        UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(1,2,100,50);
        [button setTitle:@"Test!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
   return self;
    NSLog(@"worked?"); //this log is actually outputted! However, if I put this before "return self", it doesn't work. So I'm guessing the problem is with "return self" not being caught.


}
```

view.m

```
-(IBAction)createDrawer:(id)sender {
    customButton* newButton = [customButton alloc]; 
    [newButton initWithFrame:newButton.frame]; 
    [self.containerView addSubview:newButton];
    NSLog(@"asdasdadads"); //this actually gets executed, when button is clicked
    }
```

Line 3 of view.m gives a warning "expression result unused." I'm guessing this has to do with the "return self" not being used from initWithFrame?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, and because of [class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html), you should **really** be assigning the return value of `init` to the instance:

```
customButton *newButton = [[customButton alloc] initWithFrame:f];
```

Also, conventionally class names begin with a capital letter. Name your class `CustomButton`.

**Edit:** another problem is that in the `initWithFrame:` method, you don't set the properties on `self` but on another instance (`button`). Obviously, that won't affect the state of `self`.

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestion! I forgot to mention this earlier, but I'd originally had my code set up like my latest edit (see above). This kept throwing out a warning: "Variable 'newButton' is uninitialized when used here." So I thought I'd have to "alloc" then "init." Also, it looks like the log from the CustomButton class fires before the View class, so I know that that the code in CustomButton loads first.

Comment: @Carpetfizz No, IDK why that threw a warning, it should be fine, but I rolled back the edit since with that, my answer is meaningless at first glance.

Comment: Strange, this code executes even with a warning, but I get this in the output when I click the "add" button: -[Container frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75557d0

Comment: @Carpetfizz It means that some object is not of the class you expect.

Comment: Ah, but there is only one object of the class, and it is defined in:customButton *newButton = [[customButton alloc] initWithFrame:f];

Comment: @Carpetfizz Whoops. I wanted to write that you should check your `initWithFrame:` method, and I then checked it, and you're not returning the custom button but `self` which is a different instance. Instead of creating a separate `button` instance, set the properties on `self` and it will work (additionally, you'll need to set meaningful values for the title and background color, the default is white on white which is not the best in terms of visibility).

Comment: Thanks much! Just one quick question, do I use the properties like this: self.buttonType = UIButtonTypeRoundedRectl ? Because it is giving me an error "Assignment to readonly property."

Comment: @Carpetfizz Now read the error message, and try to make sense of it. **Pretty please.** (Alternatively, you can google it too.)

Comment: Ah okay, this makes sense. It is telling me that I am trying to access a property that doesn't have "getter and setter" methods yet. So I need to use some kind of method to set the type. I tried self.buttonType=[UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];, but that obviously didn't work since there's no object to send the message to. There aren't any "setButtonType" methods either.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Actually it's that there's no setter method for `buttonType` since it's a read-only property. You can't set it.